How to give focus to file list in macOS Save As dialog rather than file name
Whenever I save an image from a browser (Firefox in my case), or use a Save As dialog anywhere else, most of the time a macOS standard Save dialog window comes up. By default, the name of the file is highlighted. 98% of the time, I would like to use the keyboard to navigate the folder structure, rather than rename the file. So I have to click in the file list panel to give it focus. Tab doesn't ever give this panel focus either. Is there a keyboard shortcut I don't know about?
